# Java StackTrace does not show where is the actual null in the line

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

The following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication7.App.main(App.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

thrown from code:

```
Object o = n1.getObj().getObj().getObj().getObj();
```

So from the stack trace it is not clear which element was actually null. Is there a method to find it out without debugging? 
Maybe some other JVM will do?

Comment: When you have a "train wreck", e.g., a line of method calls like that, all you'll know is that something in that wreck is null. It's one of several reasons why train wrecks are bad.

Comment: If you're using java8 you might want to look into the JDK class `Optional`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't figure out which of the callees in

```
Object o = obj.getObj().getObj().getObj().getObj();
```

causes the NullPointerException by looking at the stack trace. It is often recommended to format your code as

```
Object o = obj.getObj()
              .getObj()
              .getObj()
              .getObj();
```

for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can split your code, so you can see where the `NullPointerException` happens

```
MyObject obj0 = obj.getObj0();
MyObject obj1 = obj0.getObj1();
MyObject obj2 = obj1.getObj2();
MyObject obj3 = obj2.getObj3();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they all stand on the same line

```
Object o = obj.getObj0().getObj1().getObj2().getObj3();
```

You can't expect the line number to be different for one of them.

Personally, to be save I would instead separate them and check for null values, if they are possible.

```
MyObject obj0 = obj != null ? obj.getObj0() : null;
MyObject obj1 = obj0 != null ? obj.getObj1() : null;
MyObject obj2 = obj1 != null ? obj.getObj2() : null;
MyObject obj3 = obj2 != null ? obj.getObj3() : null;
```

If you really want to use chaining, then you should format it so each call is on a different line to avoid this.

```
Object o = n1.getObj()
           .getObj()
           .getObj()
           .getObj();
```